# Did Ar-Pharazon have any kids?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Did he have any kids before or after marrying Tar-Miriel? Considering how old he was when he stole the scepter from Tar-Miriel, is there an off chance he could have had kids?

Comment: He didn't need kids. His immortality was going to be living forever. Maybe he succeeded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No known offspring.

No mention is made in *The Silmarillion* or Tolkien's other writings of any children of Ar-Pharazon and Tar-Miriel, and family trees show no descendants:

[image: genealogy]

(this picture taken from [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Tar-M%C3%ADriel))